# Disable `warning.warn` messages in pylint

Tags: pylint

Pylint sometimes print following onto console

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/reporters/text.py:79: UserWarning: parseable output format is deprecated. This is equivalent to --msg-template={path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}
  % (self.name, self.line_format))
```

This causes my vim to jump to this file (`makeprg=pylint` in vimrc) rather than any error or warning in my file. I want to disable it but could not find a way to do so by modifying `.pylintrc`. Is there a way out of this?

**UPDATE**
On Fedora-20, with pylint 1.1.0, everything works file with `pylint -E` command only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you somehow use a deprecated feature of pylint (the 'parseable' output format). This may be due to a deprecated / not up to date pylint plugin for vim.

You should update the command line from `--output-format=parseable` to something like `--msg-template={path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}` which should produce equivalent output.